# Dart: how to refer to a component element, when there are multiple instances of the component?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a template:

```html
<element name="x-my-elem" constructor="MyElem" extends="div">
  <template>
    <div> 
      <button on-click="onClick()"> Button </button>
      <div id="displayMe">
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</element>
```

And script:

```dart
class MyElem {
   onClick {
      query("#displayMe").innerHtml = "hello";
   }
}
```

Now, there are multiple instances of the component in the html file:

```html
<div is="x-my-elem" id="p1" ></div>
<div is="x-my-elem" id="p2" ></div>
...
```

I want each button to change only "displayMe" that belong to it. How to achieve it?
Is there a way to generate unique Ids? Something better then this.elements[i] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you should prefer classes to id's for component internals, because you can have multiple instances of the component, as you do here.

Either way, the way to scope your query to the component is to use `this.query()` instead of `query()`, like so:

```dart
class MyElem {
   onClick {
      this.query(".displayMe").innerHtml = "hello";
   }
}
```